# map w/ object key, find, and comparison function

Tags: c++, maps

So I have a map:

```
std::map<time_t, obj*, CompFunc>
```

And I'm inserting using CompFunc based on year of time_t. I can iterate through the map and everything is inserted in order by year, exactly as I wish.  But when I:

```
typedef std::map<time_t, obj*, CompFunc>::iterator Iter;
Iter it = y.find(e1);
std::cout << ctime(&e1);  <-- prints out Mon Apr 10 17:45:00 1944, exact match to time_t object in map
std::cout << ctime(&it->first);  <-- prints out Wed Dec 31 18:00:07 1969????
```

Therefore, when I:

```
y.erase (e1);
    //or
y.erase(it->first);
```

Nothing erased.  I'm purplexed...

EDIT: Here's the comparison funct.

```
bool CompFunc::operator()(const time_t & t1, const time_t & t2) 
{                                                                               
    CmpVal = CompareYear(t1, t2);                                              
if(CmpVal != 0)                                                            
{                                                                           
    if(CmpVal == -1) {return true;}                                                       

    return false;                                                           
}                                                                           

return true;                                                                
}

 short CmpFunc::CompareYear(const time_t & t1, const time_t & t2)          
{                                                                               
    if(r1.getYear(&t1) < r2.getYear(&t2)) {return -1;}                            
    if(r1.getYear(&t1) == r2.getYear(&t2)) {return 0;}                            

return -2;                                                                  
}
```

From the .h:

```
public:                                                                     
    Cmp_event_year() {};                                                     
    ~Cmp_event_year() {};                                                    
    bool operator()(const time_t &, const time_t &);                        
private:                                                                    
    Time_t_read r1;                                                         
    Time_t_read r2;                                                         
    short CmpVal;                                                          
    short CompareYear(const time_t &, const time_t &);
```

Comment: It would be good to see your `CompFunc`.

Comment: Probably your iterator "it" is not pointing to the map position where the key is equal to e1, that means your CompFunc is not finding the right object.

Comment: I posted the CompFunc above.  Not sure why the compfunc is failing.

Comment: What are `r1` and `r2` in `CompareYear()`?

Comment: Added the .h with r1,r2.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparer returns `true` if the year of `t1` is less than *or equal to* the year of `t2`.  It needs to return `true` if and only if the year of `t1` it is less than the year of `t2`.  If the two years are equal, the comparer must return `false`.

The comparer must provide a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html).

Comment: Ahh, thank you James!  I wrote the comparer and didn't even give it a second look.  Shame on me.